# QTranslator and installTranslator

Tags: qt, qt4

i have in my project qml file with qsTr() function.
i create also a translation files for this qml.
in the main program i create a QDeclarativeView object to run the qml file, 
and also a QTranslator.
i send a pointer to this Qtranslator, and pointer to the QApplication to another function that is called when the language was changed.
at this function i write:

```
    QLocale myLocale;
    QString locale = myLocale.name();
    m_translator->load(pagePrefix +'_'+ locale);//(QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath));
    m_appManager->installTranslator(m_translator);
```

and then i loaded the qml file again.
but this didn't change the translation(and the locale was changed).
i don't know where the problem is....

Answer (score 3):

verify in your code that the translator is loaded successfuly.

```
bool loaded = false;
loaded = m_translator->load(pagePrefix +'_'+ locale);
if (!loaded)
    qWarning() << QString("can't load %1 translation").arg(locale);
```

with this you can see if your file is correctly lodad or not at all. if not verify the path of your .qm file. If yes make sure your .qm have the right translate inside.

and by the way make sure you're installing your translation

```
m_appManager->installTranslator(m_translator);
```

before you create your widgets (if I remember correctly you should do it in this order)

Comment: the QTranslator can't load the qm file... i create the qm file according to the Linguist documentations. in other applications it does work, but the change in the qml viewer file is not successful.

Comment: test if you .qm file is found with somthing like : `QFile transFile(pagePrefix +'_'+ locale); if (transFile.exists()){ /* do something */ } else { /* report error (file does not exist) */ }`